# I want to check a number in array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to check a number in an unordered array and if the number is not included in the array I want to print it and if it is included I don't want to print it, when I tried my code I thought that I could compare the array with an ordered one but it is printing the included numbers not the unincluded numbers what should i do to fix it? (the array should start from 1).

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //my max number
        int max=5;
        //my unordered array
        int[] A={1,2,3,5};
        
        //creating the ordered array
        int[] B=new int[max];
        int num=1;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            B[i]=num;
            num++;
        }
        //checking 
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < B.length; j++) {
                if (A[i]==B[j]) {
                    System.out.println(B[j]);
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
        
    
}
```

Comment: For all `j` in `B`, `B[j] == j + 1`. So your comparison is effectively `if (A[i] > 0 && A[i] <= max)` (making that inner loop pointless). You'll need to iterate the whole array in order to check if a number exists within it, but it would be _after_ that checking loop that you'd know whether or not the number you sought was in the array. If you're comfortable writing new methods, a `boolean isInArray(int[] array, int numToFind) {...}` might help simplify things.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean way to do this is to convert your input array into a Set and then iterate over all of the numbers you want to check, using the `.contains()` method to determine if each number is in the Set:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 5;
        Integer[] A={1,2,3,5};

        Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
        Collections.addAll(s, A);

        for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
            if (!s.contains(i))
                System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid the overhead of creating the Set object, you can create a function of your own that does the equivalent of the Set's `contains()` method on your original array:

```
public class Test {

    public static boolean contains(Integer[] arr, int x) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
            if (arr[j] == x)
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = 5;
        Integer[] A={1,2,3,5};

        for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
            if (!contains(A, i))
                System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

The first method will be more efficient (faster) for large arrays, while the second method will be more efficient for small ones.

In either case, the result is:

```
4
```

Yet another way would be to sort your array and then do a binary search on the array using `Arrays.binarySearch()`.  This would be particularly attractive if your incoming array was always already sorted.